# Strange behaviour of Launcher icon positions

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, icons

It's a hardly any trouble but I still want to ask in case anyone knows.

I like to keep my Launcher clean with just two or three most common applications pinned. The strange behaviour is that new applications that are not pinned in the Launcher always open up at the position just above bottom pinned one. A picture is worth a thousand words:

```
An example with 2 applications pinned     An example with 3 applications pinned
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  +------+               +------+          +------+               +------+
  | dash |               | dash |          | dash |               | dash |
  +======+               +======+          +======+               +======+
  | 1    |    launch     | 1    |          | 1    |    launch     | 1    |
  +------+  ==========>  +------+          +------+  ==========>  +------+
  | 2    |  'new' app    | new  |          | 2    |  'new' app    | 2    |
  +------+               +------+          +------+               +------+
  | s    |               | 2    |          | 3    |               | new  |
  +------+               +------+          +------+               +------+
                         | s    |          | s    |               | 3    |
                         +------+          +------+               +------+
                                                                  | s    |
                                                                  +------+
```

I can always manually position icons after launch but it would be better if pinned applications have a fixed position without an intervention in order to intuitively use shortcuts for `<super>1-9` (i.e. I could always tell that my Firefox can be reached with `<super>2` since I pinned it there).

Is there a tweak for this or maybe should it count as a bug?

Comment: To me it seems a bug but you might try unity --reset to see if the problem occurs again. Note that this will erase your unity customisations.

Comment: Tried `unity --reset` and `unity --reset-icons` now, same behavior. But I realized now that the bottom pinned application by default is the `system settings` which may be the reason why the new application is popping up just above the bottom one.

Comment: Well, I actually removed the system settings icon. It's a duplicate of the System settings in the upper right cog menu.

Comment: yes indeed it is..

Comment: reported as a bug in [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1049936) btw.

Answer (score 1):

this a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/885937

but, this bug isn't important for ubuntu team in this moment

Comment: you're right. I'm surprised it hasn't been fixed for all this time. I imagine it's just a one or two line change in a javascript file defining the layout..